# Donde está la base de datos?

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode, sqlite

Tengo un problema en mi proyecto de Xcode.

Tengo una base de datos de SQLite la cual inserto registros por código, pero cuando accedo directamente a la base de datos por SQL Vault lite y miro la tabla donde realicé el registro no me aparece aunque al realizar una consulta dentro de la aplicación sí me trae el registro que acabo de ingresar.

¿Alguien sabe si es que se está guardando en alguna otra base de datos? ¿Tal vez cuándo se copia al principio o algo así?

Comment: No se mucho sobre iOS, pero te recomiendo editar tu pregunta, separando de una mejor manera, por parrafos, y tratando de resaltar en negrita aquellas palabras que hagan relacion directa a lo que quieres

Comment: jejejeje, si que pena no soy muy bueno en ortografia y gramatica.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando pruebas en el simulador, Xcode te crea una carpeta que es donde el se monta el árbol de directorios, pone los datos etc. Esa carpeta puede variar de una compilación a otra, sobre todo si eliminas la app completa y la vuelves a crear de 0. Ademas si pruebas con un simulador version 9.0 y luego con 9.1, por ejemplo, las carpetas temporales son diferentes, al igual que si pruebas con un iPad o un iPhone. Puedes poner un log en el app delegate para que sepas donde esta ejecutando el simulador y donde están tus datos:

```
NSLog(@"PATH=%@",[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]);
```

De esta forma podrás irte a esa carpeta y veras el SQLite, y toda la información de la app

Comment: esa linea me genera un error, es swift2 y en que parte del delegate la coloco en la func application o donde? gracias :D

Comment: SI usas Swift usa esto:   print(NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]);    Lo pones dentro de func application, para que te muestre el camino cada vez que ejecutes la app

Answer (score 0):

toma en cuenta que cuando haces ABC en una base SQLite desde tu simulador o tu dispositivo, no afectas a la base que tiene tu proyecto de xcode, afectas a la base que crea el simulador o bien la base que se crea en el paquete de tu app en el dispositivo

---

creo que el codigo que te dieron para hallar el path es con objective
prueba este

```
println(NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString)
```

Comment: si estas probando en un dispositivo puedes acceder a la base desde window-> devices->iPhone/iPad seleccionas tu app y le das download container

Comment: si estas desde el simulador es un poco mas complicado pero aqui te dicen como http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644158/how-to-view-the-data-in-sqlite-file-running-in-iphone-application/4644189#4644189

Comment: espero te halla servido mi respuesta saludos

Comment: pues si y no, entonces los cambios se hacen es en una copia mmmm y donde se ubica hay no encuentro las rutas q colocan hay gracias